# Spinner's Drop Down not working properly

Tags: android, android-layout, dialog, custom-controls, spinner

I want to create `custom Spinner Dialog` for my app. I have found [this](http://adanware.blogspot.in/2012/03/android-custom-spinner-with-custom.html) & [this](http://hasmukhbhadani.blogspot.in/search/label/SpinnerView%20in%20android.).
both are good.I have update my code as per requirement. i am using selector file for changing dialog background view when user tap on spinner.

My code is working perfectly but issue is in dialog view. its spreading that width but i want to get according to some fix size.

**The current output of my Spinner View is as Follows:-**

[image]

[image]

**But i need it as Follows:-**

[image]

**Spinner_item.xml**

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/spinner_popup" // it's my selector file
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/Genere_name"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="30dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
        android:ellipsize="marquee"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:textColor="@android:color/black"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

</LinearLayout>
```

**spinner_popup.xml**

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <item android:drawable="@drawable/popup_header" android:state_selected="true"/>
    <item android:drawable="@android:color/transparent" android:state_enabled="true"/>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/popup_header" android:state_pressed="true"/>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/popup_bg_box" android:state_enabled="false" android:state_focused="true"/>
    <item android:drawable="@android:color/transparent"/>

</selector>
```

**Main_spinner_view**

```
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/search_layout"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/search_bg"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:weightSum="3" >

    <Spinner
        android:id="@+id/Search_Spinner"
        android:layout_width="95dp"
        android:layout_height="30dp"
        android:layout_gravity="left|center_vertical|center_horizontal"
        android:layout_marginLeft="2dp"
        android:layout_weight="1.2"
        android:background="@drawable/search_dropdown" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/Search_EDT"
        android:layout_width="170dp"
        android:layout_height="30dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center|center_horizontal|center_horizontal"
        android:layout_marginLeft="3dp"
        android:layout_weight="1.5"
        android:background="@drawable/search_textfield"
        android:hint="Search By Free Text"
        android:inputType="textPersonName"
        android:padding="5dp"
        android:textSize="16sp" >
    </EditText>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/Search_GO"
        android:layout_width="30dp"
        android:layout_height="30dp"
        android:layout_gravity="right|center_horizontal|center_vertical"
        android:layout_marginLeft="2dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="2dp"
        android:layout_weight="0.3"
        android:background="@drawable/search_icon"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white" />
</LinearLayout>
```

**Here i am calling my spinner adapter**

```
Search_Spinner.setAdapter(new MyAdapter(GridViewActivity.this,
                R.layout.spinner_item, Search_Category_List));
```

I think java code is not necessary but still i am paste here,

```
public class MyAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String>
    {

        public MyAdapter(Context context, int textViewResourceId,
                ArrayList<String> objects)
        {
            super(context, textViewResourceId, objects);
        }

        @Override
        public View getDropDownView(int position, View convertView,
                ViewGroup parent)
        {

            return getCustomView(position, convertView, parent);
        }

        @Override
        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
        {
            return getCustomView(position, convertView, parent);
        }

        public View getCustomView(int position, View convertView,
                ViewGroup parent)
        {

            LayoutInflater inflater = getLayoutInflater();
            View row = inflater.inflate(R.layout.spinner_item, parent, false);
            TextView label = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.Genere_name);
            spinner_text = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "desc.ttf");
            label.setTypeface(spinner_text);
            label.setText(Search_Category_List.get(position));

            return row;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Try giving the height & width of the spinner as `wrap_content` `<Spinner   android:id="@+id/Search_Spinner"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>`

Comment: but at that place i am using my spinner icon and search text box so its should be fix.

Answer (score 1):

Try create transperent activity for this

See below code for help.
First of remove Spinner control and put button over there.
Put button background like spinner so it shows like spinner.

on button click use this code

```
Intent bookIntent = new Intent();
        bookIntent.setClass(MusicAppActivity.this, OptionActivity.class);
        bookIntent.putExtra("cat", stockArr);
        startActivityForResult(bookIntent, 1);




bookIntent.putExtra("cat", stockArr);
```

pass array in intent from here
This is array which you want to display in new transperent activity.

```
OptionActivity
```

Now create one transperent activity called OptionActivity

Create list in that transperent activity.
and set width and height of activity

Transparent activity code is below

```
public class OptionActivity extends Activity {
    ListView l;
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.list);

        Intent intent = getIntent();
          String[] myStrings = intent.getStringArrayExtra("cat");


         l = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.optionList);

        l.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.headerlist,R.id.text1, myStrings));
        l.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

                  String book = l.getAdapter().getItem(position).toString();
                  Intent returnIntent = new Intent();
                  returnIntent.putExtra("SelectedBook",book);
                  setResult(RESULT_OK,returnIntent);       
                  finish();


            }
        });


    }


}
```

list.xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/optionFinish"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/my_custom_background"
    android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/headerbg" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/viewTournament"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:ellipsize="marquee"
            android:focusable="true"
            android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
            android:freezesText="true"
            android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
            android:marqueeRepeatLimit="marquee_forever"
            android:paddingLeft="15dip"
            android:paddingRight="40dip"
            android:scrollHorizontally="true"
            android:singleLine="true"
            android:text="Catagory"
            android:textColor="@android:color/white" />

        <!-- <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/optionBtn"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:background="@android:color/transparent"
            android:padding="5dip"
            android:src="@drawable/options" /> -->
    </RelativeLayout>

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/optionList"
        android:layout_width="200dip"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="right"
        android:cacheColorHint="#00000000"
        android:background="@android:color/white"
        android:paddingLeft="2dip"
        android:paddingRight="2dip" >
    </ListView>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: this will change that screen ?

Comment: You can set width and height of transparent activity as per your requirment

Comment: but i don't want to change the screen.

Comment: No screen changes. Create transparent activity only list displayed.On item select distroy your activity.I look like spinner.

Answer (score 0):

You could try to set the weight of the textview to 0.3 and the width to 0dip. You could also try to set the maxWidth on the textView. Also, the background color would have to be set for the textView and not for the spinner item as then the width would be the width of the textView.

you could also try to use the setDropDownWidth but you would have to set the minApiLevel to 16 for that. You could refer this for more : http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Spinner.html#attr_android:dropDownVerticalOffset

Comment: so your mean is that set 0.3dp in textview width and 0dp for root layout is it ?

Comment: no. set the weight to 0.3 would mean it would take 30% of the screen and setting the width to 0dip would mean that it has to take the weight to render. Both these would be on the textView.

Comment: Another option would be something like this : create a linearLayout and add 2 textViews. set the weight of the 2 textViews to 0.3 and 0.7. Let the first textView represent the item in your spinner and the second would be marked invisible.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/24958/discussion-between-lokoko-and-chintan-khetiya)

Answer (score 0):

use android:layout_width="wrap_content" instead of android:layout_width="fill_parent" in LinearLayout